# Python and lxml: get sub-sub-element from given element

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have this XML code:

```
<ProceduresDB>
  <Airport ICAOcode="EHRD">
    <Sid Name="ANDI1A" Runways="06">
      <Sid_Waypoint ID="1">
        <Latitude>0.000000</Latitude>
        <Longitude>0.000000</Longitude>
      </Sid_Waypoint>
      <Sid_Waypoint ID="2">
        <Latitude>51.973697</Latitude>
        <Longitude>4.480970</Longitude>
      </Sid_Waypoint>
    <Sid Name="ARNE2A" Runways="06">
      <Sid_Waypoint ID="1">
      etc etc
```

How do I get for example all the latitudes and longitudes for each waypoint for `Sid` with `Name='ANDI1A'`?

I've been trying to come up with something using lxml, but most tutorials/howto's do cover XML documents with nested children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.//Sid[@Name="ANDI1A"]/Sid_Waypoint` [`xpath`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

data = """<ProceduresDB>
  <Airport ICAOcode="EHRD">
    <Sid Name="ANDI1A" Runways="06">
      <Sid_Waypoint ID="1">
        <Latitude>0.000000</Latitude>
        <Longitude>0.000000</Longitude>
      </Sid_Waypoint>
      <Sid_Waypoint ID="2">
        <Latitude>51.973697</Latitude>
        <Longitude>4.480970</Longitude>
      </Sid_Waypoint>
    </Sid>
   </Airport>
</ProceduresDB>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
for waypoint in tree.findall('.//Sid[@Name="ANDI1A"]/Sid_Waypoint'):
    print "Waypoint %s" % waypoint.attrib["ID"]
    for item in waypoint:
        print item.tag, item.text
```

Prints:

```
Waypoint 1
Latitude 0.000000
Longitude 0.000000
Waypoint 2
Latitude 51.973697
Longitude 4.480970
```